# Boost header parser.hpp does not compile

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I was installing a project which uses boost. I had finished compiling. During `make all install` I faced the following error:

```
CMakeFiles/config_example.dir/__/config_impl.cc.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::run()':
/usr/local/include/boost/program_options/detail/parsers.hpp:107: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::get_canonical_option_prefix()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It reads like there is something wrong with the boost header. But this is improbable. So perhaps I am using it in the wrong way or something else is off here. Can you please help me figure out the issue. I am using boost 1.53

Comment: It reads like there is something wrong with the linking process. Maybe you forgot to link with _Boost.ProgramOptions_?

Comment: It compiles. It does not link because you are not telling it which libraries to link with.

Comment: You need to link `libboost_program_options`. Programoptions is one of the few boost libraries that is not header only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link libboost_program_options. Programoptions is one of the few boost libraries that is not header only